# Ring, domain, canonical projection and projective $A$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

The following question was asked in my assignment of modules and I am struggling on it despite thinking a lot.

> **Question:**
>
> 1. Let $A$ be a ring and $I \subset A$ an ideal. Let us suppose that the canonical projection $f \colon A \to A/I$ has a section ($f$ has a right inverse). Show that there exists $a \in A$ such that $a^2 = a$ and $I = (a)$.
> 2. Suppose that $A$ is a domain. Then show $A/I$ is a projective A-module if and only if $I = 0$ or $I = A$.

What I tried:

1. I tried to use the definition of right inverse and canonical projection but couldn’t make any progress.
2. Let $A/I$ be projective module. I have not been able to show that $I = 0$ and $I = A$. Conversaly, when  $I = A$, I have proved what was asked. But for $I = 0$, I am not able to prove what was asked.

Kindly help!

Comment: For (a) show that $A\cong I\oplus (A/I)$ by using the section. Then consider the decomposition of $1$. For (b), use (a). If $A/I$ is projective then the surjection $A\to A/I$ has a right inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence

$$ 0 \rightarrow I \xrightarrow[]{i} A \xrightarrow[]{f} A/I \rightarrow 0,$$

where $i(x) = x$. Let $g : A/I \rightarrow A$ be such that $f \circ g(z+I) = z+I$. Consider the map $h : I \oplus (A/I) \rightarrow A$ defined by $h(x,z +I) = i(x) + g(z+I) = x + g(z+I)$.

You should check this defines a ring homomorphism.

We claim this map is injective. If $(x,z+I) \in \ker(h)$, then we must have $-x = g(z+I)$. Applying $f$ to both sides, this would mean that $I = z+I$, but this can only happen if $z \in I$ and $x = 0$.

We claim this map is surjective. For $x \in A$, notice that $x - g(x+I) \in I$, since $f(x - g(x+I)) = f(x) - (x+I) = (x+I) - (x+I) = I.$ Notice that $h(x - g(x), x+I) = x - g(x+I) + g(x+I) = x$.

Putting the above together, $h$ is an isomorphism.

Consider $h^{-1} : A \rightarrow I \oplus (A/I)$. Write $h^{-1}(1) = (a, b+I)$. Notice that $h^{-1}(1^2) = (a^2, b^2+I) = (a, b+I)$, so $a^2 = a$. It should be just as easy to show that $(a) = I$ from here.

Recall $A$ is a domain if $ab = 0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$. By the prior, we have that $I = (a)$ and $a^2 = a$. Rewriting the second equality, this means $a(1-a) = 0$. So either $a = 0$, in which case $I = 0$, or $1-a =0$, in which case $a = 1$ and $I = A$.

Comment: I can't type it up right now (and will most likely forget) but this is a good point, and if OP sees this I recommend looking up ring homomorphism on Wikipedia (which explains what a rng homomorphism is).

Comment: How did you deduced that  $f(-x) \in I $ in 2nd line of 3rd paragraph? Can you please tell?

Comment: In 2nd line of 4th paragraph , how did you wrote that $f(x)=x+I$.

Comment: @IloveJesus $f$ is the canonical projection, right? $f(x) = x + I$ is the definition. If $x \in I$, then $f(x) = x + I = I$ (in my third paragraph, we are assuming $-x \in I$). Notice that $f(-x) \in I$ doesn't make sense because of where the elements live.

Comment: How did you deduced $h^{-1}(1^2) = (a^2, b^2+I) = (a, b+I)$ ? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: $h^{-1}$ is a homomorphism of rngs, so $h^{-1}(1^2) = h^{-1}(1 \cdot 1) = h^{-1}(1) \cdot h^{-1}(1) = (a^2, b^2 + I).$